# Migrating expressjs app to serverless - express-session problem

Tags: express, session, serverless

We have a typical express app implemented (it's mostly a rest api, but also has some other logic like passport-js login flows and session management in it). Now migrating it to serverless with AWS Lambdas. The original express app uses express-session package to maintain session info with postgres as the store. App is deployed to AWS now - first request works, then second request fails with Internal Server Error. We have a hard time figuring out why. It's not a timeout. We tried setting up express-session with postgres, DynamoDB and in-memory - and still could not make it work. Why is that so? What is the recommended solution for session management when it comes to a serverless app?

Comment: Do you have some error messages to show?

Comment: What do log files record regarding *"Internal Server Error"*?

Comment: Sorry, no more error messages. Only "Internal Server Error" and also empty json response.

Comment: Have you checked CloudWatch for further logs?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use the JSON Token. The session are stored directly on the client side.

In theory, at first connexion, you set a token for the session, and send it to the client.

Each time the user call the Api, you send the JSON Token. On the server side, you fill it with the data you need (it's an object)... And send it again to the client...

There are a lot of implementation of this process, and with JWT:

https://serverless.com/blog/strategies-implementing-user-authentication-serverless-applications/
https://ponyfoo.com/articles/json-web-tokens-vs-session-cookies
....

---

According to Amazon, the best approch to manage session is to set it in a third party, as you tried you said...

https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/going-serverless-migrating-an-express-application-to-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/

Extract :

```
* Storing local state is unreliable due to automatic scaling. Consider going stateless (using REST),
* or use an external state store (for MongoDB, you can use the connect-mongo package)
app.use(session({ secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET }))
*/
```

> Removed session state for scalability (alternatively, you could have
>   stored session state in MongoDB using connect-mongo.

So as the Amazon best practice says, you should try to implement it via mongo.

That's the recommended approach as it comes from Amazon directly...

Comment: I know JWT and I don't want to use them in this case. I want to understand what makes the express app hang upon 2nd request when express-session is used. Must be some aws lambda specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Session management is fundamentally different in a stateless, serverless environment.

Since you haven't shared the code that generates the errors, I can only speak in generalities.  The general approach is to store any state information in your database, and poll the database when an operation needs to know that state.  Alternatively, you can use a listener in that database node to detect changes and propogate these to the front end.

To address your error -- again hypothetically, since there's no code to go off of -- if you've migrated an Express app to serverless + database, and your first request succeeds but second one fails, you've probably got an error handling promises or somewhere in your asynchronous flow between function and DB.

I'd look at https://levelup.gitconnected.com/avoiding-the-pitfalls-of-async-node-js-functions-in-aws-lambda-941220582e7a and put some console.log statements at various points before and after database access to see if you're getting the actual data you expect, or an as-yet unresolved promise.  Best of luck!

Comment: "you've probably got an error handling promises or somewhere in your asynchronous flow" --> yes, that is helpful. But what I am after: why a rejected promise is problem in serverless + lambda Normally such a thing does not hang a process.

Comment: Not a rejected promise, but one that is left dangling and resolved after your lamda invocation ends.  It's not a server that's permanently up.  That's an issue with all cloud function platforms, not just AWS.